# segmentation fault in c++ using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I was solving the problem to find all possible substrings of a string using recursion but I was getting segmentation fault.

```js
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void subset(string s,string output){
    if(s.length()==0){
        cout<<output<<" ";
        return ;
    }
   
    string op1=output;
    string op2=output;
    op2.push_back(s[0]);
    s.erase(s.begin()+0);
    subset(op1,output);
    subset(op2, output);
    return;
    
}

int main(){
    subset("ab","");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Take a step back and really think about what you're trying to achieve. Design before starting to program. Write out the steps that have to be followed to get the result you want. Explain it to an imaginary person (rubber duck programming). Then write or the steps as comments in the code and start to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You sending wrong string in recursive call does this work

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void dubset(string s,string output){
    if(s.length()==0){
        cout<<output<<" ";
        return ;
    }
   
    string op1=output;
    string op2=output;
    op2.push_back(s[0]);
    s.erase(s.begin()+0);
    dubset(s,op1);
    dubset(s, op2);
    return;
    
}

int main(){
    dubset("ab","");

    return 0;
}
```